# How can i make input field read only but still able to scroll value

Tags: html, css

I want to disable edit on input field, but still want to view all input value that works in any browser. 
e.g

```
<input readonly values="asdfbaasdfkadfjakdlfkakdflakjdkfjalsdjfkajdkfjalsjfklajdkjfalkjdfkajsdflkakdf" />
```

Comment: You can't click the field and drag with your mouse to see the text? Works for me.

Comment: thanks for the answer man.. I already solved this, I created a js script to enable arrow keys to view all value in addition to mouse drag.

Comment: What about scrolling using keyboard alone? I'm working on something that has to be 508 compliant and I have a text field which is read only under certain circumstances. There are arrows next to the text field which will allow scrolling by clicking the mouse, but because it is read only I can't shift focus to the field with tab and thus I can't scroll down with the keyboard. Any ideas?